# Hide a row hover a specific cell

Tags: css, row, cell, tabulator

I'm a CSS beginner and I struggle with this problem :
in a table, I have a CSS to display a line when I'm hover a row...
But if I'm hover a specific cell (the second column from the left in my example), I want the row line to hide
I cannot fix that

[pict example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp2q8.png)

this is the code I use

```
.secondCell:hover {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    border-width: 1px
}

.tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable:hover {
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FD9A00;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

thanks

Comment: not sure if I understand. You want to avoid double border-bottom (orange and purple) on one cell. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I'd suggest a solution like this.

```css
tbody td:not(:nth-child(3)):hover {
  /* your hover properties here */
}
```

[The `:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) will *not* select an element if whatever inside the parentheses matches.

[The `:nth-child(x)` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selects a specific child. It also accepts `odd` org `even` as an argument.

In the future, please be more specific and provide an example of your HTML as well. It's hard to provide help when there is little to go on.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, but I use tabulator library, I can control CSS and the class but not the element (td, tr) - it's my mistake, I add tabulator tag in my question

Comment: I have 2 different elements, with 2 different hover 1 hover on the cell and 1 hover on the row....I just want to get rid of the 'row:hover' when the cell:hover is activated, to provide an html example is tricky, cause I use tabulator library witch create is own...